# Use String.split() with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string base on delimiter `-` and `.`. Below are my desired output.

`AA.BB-CC-DD.zip` ->

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
zip
```

but my following code does not work.

```
private void getId(String pdfName){
    String[]tokens = pdfName.split("-\\.");
}
```

Comment: Based on what you said, it looks like it is working fine. What is your desired output?

Comment: @Jeff: He showed his desired output (`AA` / `BB` / `CC` ...)

Comment: Are you sure? I interpreted that as his current output, not his desired output. Maybe its time to stand up and walk around a little bit.

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry for the confusion, I updated my post to clear your misunderstand.

Comment: Regex will degrade your performance. I would recommend write a method which will go character by character and split string if need. You can optimize this futher to get log(n) performance.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

I think you need to include the regex **OR operator**:

```
String[]tokens = pdfName.split("-|\\.");
```

What you have will match:
[DASH followed by DOT together] `-.`
not
[DASH or DOT any of them]  `-` or `.`

Comment: why we require two backslashes ??

Comment: The `.` character in regex means any character other than new line. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm In this case, however, they wanted the actual character `.`. The two backslashes indicate that you are referring to `.`. The backslash is an escape character.

Comment: for normal cases it would be `.split("match1|match2")`, (eg. `split("https|http")`), \\ is to escape the special char `.` in above case

Comment: or generally, you can use `pdfName.split("\\W");` as below @Peter Knego answer

Comment: use `[-.]` instead of `-|\\.`

Answer (score 71):

Try this regex `"[-.]+"`. The + after treats consecutive delimiter chars as one. Remove plus if you do not want this.

Comment: @Lurkers: The only reason Peter didn't have to escape that `-` was that it's the *first* think inside the `[]`, otherwise there would need to be a backslash in front of it (and of course, to put a backslash in front of it, we need *two* because this is a string literal).

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted one, because when you use the logical operator |, the problem is that one of your delimiters can be a part of your result 'tokens'.
This will not happen with Peter Knego's [-.]+

Answer (score 32):

You can use the regex "\W".This matches any non-word character.The required line would be:

```
String[] tokens=pdfName.split("\\W");
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me ` String s = "id(INT), name(STRING),". Using \\W here creates an array of length 6 where as it should be only 4

Comment: This will also break when the input contains Unicode character. It's best to only include the actual delimiter, instead of a "grab all" with `\W`.

Answer (score 19):

The string you give `split` is the string form of a regular expression, so:

```
private void getId(String pdfName){
    String[] tokens = pdfName.split("[-.]");
    // ...
}
```

That means "split on any character within the `[]`" (so, split on `-` and `.`). A couple of notes on that:

1. Normally, you have to escape the dot (`.`) by putting a backslash in front of it because in a regular expression `.` means "any character." But you don't have to do that within a character class (`[]`).
2. Normally, within a character class (`[]`), you have to escape the dash (`-`) because in that context it has special meaning (it indicates a range, like `[0-9A-Fa-f]` to match all hex digits). But when it's the **first** character after the `[`, we don't have to escape it.

If you **did** need to escape either of those, the way you'd do it is by having a backslash in front of it in the string. Since we're writing this as a string *literal*, to actually put a backslash in the string requires that we escape it, since otherwise it's an escape character (for instance, `\n` means newline, `\t` means tab, etc.). So we'd have to write `\\` to put an actual backslash in the string for the regular expression engine to see it and use it to escape the next character (`-` or `.`). For instance, `"[\\-.]"` if we wanted to escape the `-` even though we don't need to.

Live example: https://ideone.com/PMA8d3

Comment: You don't need to escape the hyphen in this case, because `[-.]` couldn't possibly be interpreted as a range.

Comment: @Alan: Because it's the very first thing in the class, that's quite true. But I always do, it's too easy to go back later and add something in front of it without thinking. Escaping it costs nothing, so...

Comment: do you know how to escape the brackets? I have String "[200] Engineering" that I want to split into "200" , "Engineering"

Comment: Oh wow I got it...I had to use two backslashes instead of one. `String[] strings = codes.get(x).split("\\[|\\]| ");` <-- code for anyone interested

Comment: Can you explain why we need to "escape the backlash because this is a string?"

Comment: @Goh-shans - I didn't phrase that well (I've updated it). In a string *literal*, a backslash is an escape character (`\n` means newline, `\t` means tab, etc.). So to put a backslash in the string, we have to escape it (with a backslash). So `"[\\-.]"` creates a regular expression using the string `[\-.]`, which escapes the `-`. **But**, there's no need to do that when the `-` is the first character after the `[` anyway.

Answer (score 16):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you could do this:

```
Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("-.")).split(pdfName);
```

Answer (score 10):

For two char sequence as delimeters "AND" and "OR" this should be worked. Don't forget to trim while using.

```
 String text ="ISTANBUL AND NEW YORK AND PARIS OR TOKYO AND MOSCOW";
 String[] cities = text.split("AND|OR");
```

Result : cities = {"ISTANBUL ", " NEW YORK ", " PARIS ", " TOKYO ", " MOSCOW"}

Comment: How can I get output like {"ISTANBUL AND", " NEW YORK AND", " PARIS OR", " TOKYO AND", " MOSCOW"}

Answer (score 6):

`pdfName.split("[.-]+");`

- `[.-]` -> any one of the `.` or `-` can be used as delimiter
- `+` sign signifies that if the aforementioned delimiters occur consecutively we should treat it as one.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use Apache Commons:

import `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`

```
private void getId(String pdfName){
    String[] tokens = StringUtils.split(pdfName, "-.");
}
```

It'll split on any of the specified separators, as opposed to `StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(str, separator)` which uses the complete string as a separator

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] token=s.split("[.-]");
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use something like this:

```
s.split("[\\s\\-\\.\\'\\?\\,\\_\\@]+");
```

Have added a few other characters as sample. This is the safest way to use, because the way `.` and `'` is treated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
var string = 'AA.BB-CC-DD.zip';
array = string.split(/[,.]/);
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You may also specified regular expression as argument in split() method ..see below example....

```
private void getId(String pdfName){
String[]tokens = pdfName.split("-|\\.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s.trim().split("[\\W]+")
```

should work.

Comment: First, no, it does not work - maybe you can try it before posting? Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters#answer-13928086) is same as your - but working. Finally you should check your formating (_should work._).

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way as split accepts varargs so we can pass multiple parameters as delimeters

```
 String[]tokens = pdfName.split("-",".");
```

you can pass as many parameters that you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the sting will always be in the same format, first split the string based on `.` and store the string at the first index in a variable. Then split the string in the second index based on `-` and store indexes 0, 1 and 2. Finally, split index 2 of the previous array based on `.` and you should have obtained all of the relevant fields.

Refer to the following snippet:

```
String[] tmp = pdfName.split(".");
String val1 = tmp[0];
tmp = tmp[1].split("-");
String val2 = tmp[0];
...
```

Comment: It can be done in one step, so do it in one step. See the other replies.

Comment: `pdfName.split(".")` results in a zero-length array.

Comment: 1)  `.` Needs to be escaped as `\\.`