# Splitting a string in java where the delimiter is a word

Tags: java, string

I hava a string(A list of author names for a book) which is of the following format:

`author_name1`, `author_name2`, `author_name3` and `author_name4`

How can I parse the string so that I get the list of author names as an array of `String`. (The delimiters in this case are `,` and the word `and`. I'm not sure how I can split the string based on these delimiters (since the delimiter here is a word and not a single character).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `myString.split(",|and")` it will do what you want :)

Answer (score 7):

You should use regular expressions:

```
"someString".split("(,|and)")
```

Comment: I don't think you need the parentheses, do you ?

Comment: @C4stor, huh, actually it does not matter here. I am used to use parentheses.

Comment: Parentheses doesn't change what the code does, but simpler code is usually preferred for readability (even if there's only a slight difference in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
yourString.split("\\s*(,|and)\\s*")
```

`\\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters (so the surrounding spaces aren't included in your split).

`(,|and)` means `,` or `and`.

[Test](https://ideone.com/gBtX5W) (`Arrays.toString` prints the array in the form - `[element1, element2, ..., elementN]`).

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the regex OR operator:

```
String[]tokens = someString.split(",|and");
```