# Java String Splitting

Tags: java, string

```
"2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM"
```

I want to split the above string in Java into the following parts: 2, 17, 2014, 11, 55, 00, PM.

I was thinking of using something like-

```
String[] parts = string.split("[/ :]");
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.  I would like to split everything in one command, if at all possible.

Comment: What did you try? What result did you get? "It doesn't work" isn't sufficient for us to help you.

Comment: Looks like you try to parse a date. Any reason you do not want to use SimpleDateFormat or some JodaTime class to parse it?

Comment: It works for me. Where's the problem?

Comment: It is working with me though.

Comment: Your RegExp works fine, so your problem is probably in the surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String[] strings = "2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM".split("/| |:");
```

Also try replacing with ", " if you want just one String:

```
 String x = "2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM".replaceAll("/| |:", ", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with the way you're looking for spaces. Try

```
[:\\s\\/]
```

It will look for a colon (:), a "space character" (tab or space), and then a slash (which you have to escape with a backslash).

Answer (score 0):

You can split using a regex expression like so:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM";
        String[] parts = s.split("/|:| ");
        for (String p : parts)
            System.out.println(p);  
    }   
}
```

The pipe '|' operator in the regex expression means OR. So your criteria is forward slash, colon, or space.

This produces the following.

```
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
2
17
2014
11
55
00
PM
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here, guess: [Use String.split() with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters)

```
String a="2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM";
String[]tokens = a.split("/| |:");
```

Try it

Answer (score 0):

it works for me :

```
  String s="2/17/2014 11:55:00 PM";
  String[] parts = s.split("[/ :]");
```

The output :

```
for (String s: parts)
    System.out.println(s);
```

==>

```
run:
2
17
2014
11
55
00
PM
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```