# How to split a a string in java by multiple delimiters with padding spaces?

Tags: java, regex, string

We tried many forms of regular expressions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters). Our input string is

`"string1 & string2 / string3"`

and we would like to split it into the string into

`{"string1","string2","string3"}`

on the delimiters `&` and `/` (with one space of padding for each).

How can we construct a regular expression to do this using `string.split(" [/&] ")`?

Comment: Your RegEx looks correct - what's the issue?

Comment: Yes, my bad, it was a bug completely unrelated to splitting.  I'll close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't got ur question correctly, what you have mentioned is perfectly ok.

And if you want this :: {"string1","string2","string3"}

simply do :
System.out.println( "{\"" + s.replaceAll( " [/&] ", "\",\"") + "\"}" );

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one.

```
String[] result = string.split(" & | / ");
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] split = s.split("[&//] ");
```

Comment: It works, but if you insist, you can also use: s.split("[&\\/] ")

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (String part : "string1 & string2 / string3".split(" [/|&] ")) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
```

So what you're interested in is the **.split(" [/|&] ")** part

Answer (score 0):

Just try with

```
String input = "string1 & string2 / string3";
boolean first = true;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\"");

for (String part : input.split(" [&/] ")) {
    if (!first) {
        sb.append("\",\"");
    }
    sb.append(part);
    first = false;
}

String output = sb.append("\"}").toString();
```

Output:

```
{"string1","string2","string3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs just fine.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class StringDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "string1 & string2 / string3";
    String delimiters = " [/&] ";

    // analyzing the string
    String[] tokensVal = str.split(delimiters);

    // prints the number of tokens
    System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + tokensVal.length);

    for(String token : tokensVal) {
       System.out.println("#" + token + "#");
    }
  }
}
```