# Split using multiple keywords as demiliters

Tags: java, split

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters) question answers how we can split a string using multiple delimiters?
Is it also possible to split a String using multiple keywords.

For example:

```
String myString = (One Two Three) AND (Four Five Six) OR (Six Seven Eight)
```

And I want to split `myString` at both `AND` and `OR` so that I get:

```
  someArray[0] = (One Two Three)

  someArray[1] = (Four Five Six)

  someArray[2] = (Six Seven Eight)
```

I do not know much of `regex`, so any help or advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to process an expression of sorts. If that is the case, using a simple `split` will prove too limiting very soon (specifically, when you add a second level of parentheses). Consider switching your approach to something more robust - say, a simple recursive descent parser.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight a simple recursive descent parser? My knowledge is limited on that. Could you be more elaborate?

Comment: You can read more about recursive descent parsers on wikipedia. They could be really small - here is a [link to a tutorial](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s5.html) explaining how to write a small but useable recursive descent parser that understands expressions with arbitrary level of parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
String[] someArray=yourString.split("(AND)|(OR)");
```

Comment: Thank you so much  @Mifmif I was looking for this exact answer

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(One Two Three) AND (Four Five Six) OR (Six Seven Eight)";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(AND|OR)")));

}
```

O/P :

```
[(One Two Three) ,  (Four Five Six) ,  (Six Seven Eight)]
```

Comment: how to know what delimiters caused the split?

Comment: @tsypa - The delimiter you used will be used for splitting :P