# How to check a String for multiple items in a String ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList and add strings that I'm checking for to it like this.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("is");
    al.add("the");
```

Then I have a method that returns a match found in the String that is also in the ArrayList.

```
public static String getWord(String str1, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str1.toLowerCase().contains(list.get(i)))
        {
            return list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Although when I want to check a String that has more than one match it only returns the fist one that was added into the ArrayList, so

```
al.add("is");
al.add("the");
```

it would return "is"

If I add them like this

```
al.add("the");
al.add("is");
```

it would return "the"

I need a way of determining how many matches there are and returning them individually.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: To extend on Raedwald's comment, you can't return `false` in a method with a declared return type of `String`

Comment: Please post how you are invoking getWord in your code

Comment: As Raedwald mentioned, `getWord` function will throw compilation error because its return type is `String` but you return `false` if `str1` is not in the `list`

Comment: how can a method with a return type of String return multiple matches from the list?

Comment: sorry my bad I meant to return null there it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Map to hold, key as the string in List and value will be count matched

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("aa");
    list.add("bb");
    list.add("cc");
    list.add("dd");
    list.add("ee");
    list.add("ff");
    list.add("kk");
    list.add("ff");

    System.out.println(getWord("aabbccddeeff", list));
}

public static Map<String, Integer> getWord(String str1, List<String> list)
{
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Integer count = 1;

    for (String match : list)
    {
        if(str1.toLowerCase().contains(match))
        {
            if(map.containsKey(match))
            {
                count = map.get(match);
                count++;

            }
            map.put(match, count);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Or use a MultiSet...which is the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another array  list to hold the matches

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("is");
al.add("the");
//...

ArrayList<String> result = getWord("something", a1);

// return matches individually with indexes or use indexOf...
result.get(1);
result.get(result.indexOf("something random"));


// how many matches = size of the array list
result.size();


// ...

public static ArrayList<String> getWord(String str1, ArrayList<String> list)
{

    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    String testString = str1.toLowerCase();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(testString.contains(list.get(i)))
        {
            matches.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### `O(nm)` Solution:

If your String is length `m` and your list is length `n`, the algorithm you show in your original question runs in `O(mn)` time complexity because it has to loop through the entire list `O(n)` and then search the entire string `O(m)`.

### `O(n+m)` Solution:

However, you can do much better *if* the String can first be separated into individual words (e.g. `"The dog jumped"` would give `["The", "dog", "jumped"]`). In this case you can have a running time of `O(m + n)` by first separating your String into individual words stored in a `HashSet<String>`, and then searching the set for each word in the list.

E.g.

```
Set<String> getWords(String str, Set<String> words){  // using set removes dups

    Set<String> indvWords = getIndividualWords(str);  // O(m)
    Set<String> matchedWords = new HashSet<String>(); // O(1)      

    for(String word : words)                          // O(n)
        if(indvWords.contains(word))                  // O(1)
            matchedWords.add(word);                   // O(1) 

    return matchedWords;
}                                                     // total: O(m + n)
```

Of course, you would have to implement `Set<String> getIndividualWords(String str)` yourself, perhaps using [`String#split(String)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993823/1290264) with a [`regex` pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), e.g.:

```
Set<String> getIndividualWords(String str){
    return new HashSet<String>(str.split("\\W")); // split string by non words
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void getWord(String str1, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str1.toLowerCase().contains(list.get(i)))
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```