# Java String.split : Trouble using \\W as non word delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

Going by the suggestion provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters)
I tried using \\W as a delimiter for non word character in string.split function of java.

```
String str = "id-INT, name-STRING,";
```

This looks like a really simple string. I wanted to extract just the words from this string. The length of the array that I get is 5 whereas it should be 4. There is an empty string at position right after INT. I don't understand why the space in there is not being considered as non word

Comment: The `,` and the space are been treated as separate entities, try using `\\W+` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `,` and the space are been treated as separate entities, try using `\\W+` instead

```
    String str = "id-INT, name-STRING,";
    String[] parts = str.split("\\W+");
    System.out.println(parts.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Which outputs

```
4
[id, INT, name, STRING]
```

Comment: I tried googling the significance of + sign here. Didn't get any. Could you please explain what did the + sign do? BTW : Thank you very much

Comment: From my (puny) understanding, it's grouping all the entities together, so rather than using the individual elements, it's group all the matches that occur simultaneously (`", "`) together into a single match