# Extracting text between multiple Delimiters

Tags: java, regex, delimiter, text-extraction, csv

I need to extract a specific string from a text file that has lines with multiple Delimiters that may be similar or different. For example, lets say I have a text file contains the below lines. Let's consider each text between a delimiter as a segment.

```
ABC#12#3#LINE1####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z:1234:1234561230$
ABC#12#3#LINE TWO####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z:1234:4564561230$
ABC#12#3#3RD LINE####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z*1234:7894561230$
```

I need to write a code that extracts the text after `ABC#12#3#` in all the lines in the text file, based on two inputs.

1) The segment to find (e.g., `ABC`)

2) Position of the segment from which I need to extract the text. (e.g., `4`)

So, an input of `ABC` and 4th segment will give a result - `LINE1` and an input of `DEF` and 5th segment will give a result - `1234678985`.
This is what I've got so far regarding the 1st input.

```
scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
line = scanner.nextLine();
if (line.contains(find)){   // find is the 1st input - (e.g., ABC)
System.out.println("Line to be replaced - "+ line);
int ind1 = line.indexOf(findlastchar+"*")+1;
int ind2 = line.indexOf("*");
System.out.println("Ind1 is "+ ind1+ " and Ind2 is " + ind2);
System.out.println("findlastchar is "+findlastchar+"#");
remove = line.substring(line.indexOf(findlastchar)+1, line.indexOf("#"));
System.out.println("String to be replaced " + remove);
content = content.replaceAll(remove, replace);
    }
}
```

I've got 2 problems with my code. I don't know how I can use `substring` to separate text between SAME delimiters and I'm not sure how to write the code such that it is able to identify all the following special characters as delimiters - `{#, $, :}` and thereby consider any text between ANY of these delimiters as a segment.

Answer to [this](http://www.yahoo.com/) question uses regex which I want to avoid.

Comment: You have many special characters there, note that `replaceAll` accepts a *regex*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: use split() with multiple delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the line and use index:

```
public String GetItemFromLine(String s, String delimiter, String prefix, int index) {
   String[] items = s.split(delimiter);
   return items[0] == prefix ? items[index] : null;
}
```

PS I have no experience with Java so please treat this example as pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), where you can pass the delimiters as a String, and then loop over it (See this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/)) or even better use String.split with a regexp:

```
String[] words = line.split("#|$|:");
```

Answer (score 0):

It its probably not the most efficient way, but you can do it with regex, for example:

```
(ABC[#:*$]+(?:\w+[#:*$]+){2}|DEF[#:*$]+(?:\w+[#:*$]+){3})([^#:*$]+)(.+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW3tW1/1)

Where with `{2}` and `{3}` (nambers of repetitions of given pattern) you decide which part of string should be repleced. In this case you change only fragment between delimiters.
Example in Java:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lines = {"ABC#12#3#LINE1####1234678985$",
                "DEF#XY#Z:1234:1234561230$",
                "ABC#12#3#LINE TWO####1234678985$",
                "DEF#XY#Z:1234:4564561230$",
                "ABC#12#3#3RD LINE####1234678985$",
                "DEF#XY#Z*1234:7894561230$"};
        for (String line : lines) {
            String result = line.replaceAll("(ABC[#:*$]+(?:\\w+[#:*$]+){2}|DEF[#:*$]+(?:\\w+[#:*$]+){3})([^#:*$]+)(.+)","$1" + " replacement " + "$3");
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
ABC#12#3# replacement ####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z:1234: replacement $
ABC#12#3# replacement ####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z:1234: replacement $
ABC#12#3# replacement ####1234678985$
DEF#XY#Z*1234: replacement $
```