# How to delete a line from text line by id java

Tags: java

How to delete a line from a text file java?
I searched everywhere and even though I can't find a way to delete a line.
I have the text file: a.txt

```
 1, Anaa, 23
 4, Mary, 3
```

and the function taken from internet:

```
public void removeLineFromFile(Long id){
   try{
       File inputFile = new File(fileName);
       File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\...myTempFile.txt");

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
       BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

       String lineToRemove = Objects.toString(id,null);
       String currentLine;

       while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
           String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
           String trimmLine[] = trimmedLine.split(" ");
           if(!trimmLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
               writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
           }
       }
       writer.close();
       reader.close();
       boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
   }catch (IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

where the fileName is the path for a.txt.
I have to delete the line enetering the id.That's why I split the trimmedLine. At the end of execution I have 2 files, the a.txt and myTempFile both having the same lines(the ones from beginning). Why couldn't delete it?

Comment: Because you're comparing the text on the line with a number called `id`

Comment: `lineToRemove` is always just the String representation of the `Long` input, while `trimmLine` is some kind of line in your given format. You'll want to extract the id from `trimmLine`  and then compare the two

Comment: But I tried to convert the number into a string: String lineToRemove = Objects.toString(id,null);

Comment: @Marv and how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete the line whose id matches with the id passed in the `removeLineFromFile` method.

To make your code work, only few changes are needed. 
To extract the id, you need to split using both `" "` and `","`

i.e.

```
           String trimmLine[] = trimmedLine.split(" |,");
```

where `|` is the regex OR operator.
See [Java: use split() with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters).

Also, trimmLine is an array, you can't just compare trimmLine with lineToRemove. You first need to extract the first part which is the id from trimmLine. I would suggest you to look at the working of `split` method if you have difficulty in understanding this. You can have a look at [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).

So, extract the id which is the first index of the array trimmLine here using:

```
           String part1 = trimmLine[0];
```

and then compare part1 with lineToRemove.

Whole code looks like:

```
public void removeLineFromFile(Long id){
   try{
      File inputFile = new File(fileName);
      File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\...myTempFile.txt");

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

      String lineToRemove = Objects.toString(id,null);
      String currentLine;

      while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
          String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
          String trimmLine[] = trimmedLine.split(" |,");
          String part1 = trimmLine[0];

          if(!part1.equals(lineToRemove)) {
              writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          }
      }
      writer.close();
      reader.close();
      boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
   }catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```