# Split multiple delimiters in Java

Tags: java, split, count, delimiter, frequency

How I can split the sentences with respect to the delimiters in the string and count the frequency of words ?

```
 String delimiters = "\t,;.?!-:@[](){}_*/";
```

**My text file is:**

```
Billy_Reeves

Smorz

Nationalist_Left_-_Youth

Ancient_Greek_units_of_measurement

Jiuting_(Shanghai_Metro)

Blodgett,_MO

Baekjeong

Matt_Brinkman

National_Vietnam_Veterans_Art_Museum
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with

```
split("\\t|,|;|\\.|\\?|!|-|:|@|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}|_|\\*|/");
```

Also

[Use String.split() with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/java-use-split-with-multiple-delimiters)

Comment: You seems to know that `split` takes regex, but forgot that some characters in regex are special and may require escaping. In current form this code will throw PatternSyntaxException since it is not properly created regex.

Comment: Fixed now @Pshemo

Answer (score 3):

The split method takes as argument a regular expression so, to use multiple delimiters, you need to input a regular expression separated by the OR regex operator or using a character class (only if the delimiters are single characters).

Using the OR operator:

```
String delimiters = "\\t|,|;|\\.|\\?|!|-|:|@|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}|_|\\*|/";
```

Using the character class:

```
String delimiters = "[-\\t,;.?!:@\\[\\](){}_*/]";
```

As you can see some of the characters must be escaped as they are regex metacharacters.