# Reading semicolon delimited csv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have the below block of code which uses OpenCSV to read a CSV file and store the 7th column. The problem I face is that I use `;` as delimiter in the CSV file but it takes `,` as delimiter as well. How can I avoid this?

Putting "" in CSV is not possible, since we get a non-editable file from client.

```
        CSVReader reader = null;
    String[] nextCsvLine = new String[50];
    String splitBy = ";";

    int count = 0;

    try {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(new String(in, offset, len));
        reader = new CSVReader(sr);

        while ((nextCsvLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (String linewithsemicolon : nextCsvLine) {
                log.debug("Line read : "+linewithsemicolon);
                String[] b = linewithsemicolon.split(splitBy);
                if (count==0){
                    count++;
                    continue;
                }
                else    {      
                    detailItems.add(b[7]);
                    log.debug("7th position: "+b[7]);
                    count++;
                }                   
            }
```

Comment: Which language is this? It looks like Java. You need to tag your question with the programming language - see the "edit" link under your question.

Comment: Yes its JAVA sorry forgot to link.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't react on commas at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: To simplify my question, is it possible that I only read till this 8th column and then skip to the next line?. Line may have 30 columns or even more but I just want to read 8th column and move to next line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters this will help you -> same approach

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParserBuilder.html#withSeparator(char).

Comment: Note that `for (String linewithsemicolon : nextCsvLine)` already indicates your problem: `nextCsvLine` indicates a line represented as a collection or array of elements while `linewithsemicolon` indicates you're treating _one_ element as a line. That doesn't fit well and should already hint at problems with the reader. As already answered you can provide a delimiter to the CSVReader but in case this were not possible then using CSVReader at all would have been a questionable decision.

Comment: My point is even if I don't want this replacement thing at all, is it possible to just skip the entire line after reading the 8th column.

Comment: Thomas can you help with this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the overloaded version with separator of [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/)

```
CSVReader(reader, ';')
```

Update (thanks to @Matt) - better use:

```
CSVReaderBuilder(reader)
    .withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder()
        .withSeparator(';')
        .build()
    ).build()
```

---

I think the `count`ing was done a bit wrong:

```
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(sr, ';')) {
    String[] nextCsvLine;
    while ((nextCsvLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String field: nextCsvLine) {
            log.debug("Line read : "+linewithsemicolon);
            if (count == 6) { // 7th column
                detailItems.add(field);
                log.debug("7th position: " + field);
            }                   
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Instead the for-loop you could have done:

```
         if (nextCsvLine.length > 6) {
             detailItems.add(nextCsvLine[6]);
         }
```

Where the seventh field should have index 6.

Comment: Did you mean something like reader = new CSVReader(sr,';');

This breaks after the first instance of semicolon and doesn't read after that.

Comment: See [ReadNumbers2.java](http://zetcode.com/articles/opencsv/) from zetcode.com. I'll add some code to the answer.

Comment: Fyi: As of the latest version OpenCSV uses the builder pattern which renders the constructor with the delimiter as 2nd parameter deprecated. It's now `CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withCSVParser(CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build())` See http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html

Comment: @Matt I took the liberty to move the code into the answer to prevent deprecated code copies.