# Extraxting subStrings form String

Tags: java, parsing

Suppose i have this string : `"X1 + X2 = Y3 + Y4 * Y5"` , from this string i wanna get an array `{X1,X2,Y3,Y4,Y5}`
My problem is how manage the following case : `"X11 + X2 = Y3 + Y4 * Y5"` , in this case i would get an array : `{X1,X11,X2,Y3,Y4,Y5}` and this is wrong because `"X1"` doesn't exist .

I didn't develop any algorithm yet , my idea was two declare two arrays with values from `X1..XN` and `Y1..YN` and for each value check if it is contained in my string , but in this way i will have a trouble explained above .

I would like to know how to do it ,  i would prefer not to use any external library to do this .

Comment: You can use split with multiple delimiters. [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters) is a case like yours.

Comment: Your question should include all relevant details. You say that in your case you got wrong results, yet you don't explain how you got them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split with this regex `\\P{Alnum}+` which split in any one or more non alphanumerical your solution can be :

```
String text = "X11 + X2 = Y3 + Y4 * Y5";
String[] split = text.split("\\P{Alnum}+");//This equivalent to "[^a-zA-Z\\d]+"
```

Outputs

```
[X11, X2, Y3, Y4, Y5]
```

Comment: Maybe the spaces are optional. In that case I'ld prefer the regular expression "\\W+"

Comment: Thank you @RobertKock correct `"\W+"` can also solve the problem

Comment: Thank you guys for your effort and your time , i found my solution and i wanna share with you , answered below

Answer (score 1):

My Own solution is :

```
String patternString = "[X|Y]{1}\\d+";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        }
```

**[X|Y]{1}\\d+** means X or Y letter which appear only once followed from any number of digits

Comment: You mean `"(X|Y)\\d+"` you don't need to specify `{1}` because by default is one