# csv with two delimiters

Tags: java, bufferedreader, csv

I am trying to read a csv  with two delimiters, which has the following format:

```
    Payment Date,Amount,Member No/branchno
    2018/01/25,58,294416/0
```

the first part is the date and the last column is the column I am facing issues with. I need to split that last column into two columns after the slash.

my problem is that i do not know how to separate the last column without affecting the first column, any Help is really appreciated.

I can already read through the csv and split the commas.
here is the code for reading through the csv:

```
public ArrayList<String[]> ReadCSVFile(File DataFile)
    {    
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(DataFile));){ 

         //while loop to read through the data, while bufferedreader is not null-do .... 
                 while(reader.readLine()!= null)
                {
                    String read = reader.readLine();//bufferedreader string variable
                    String[] OneRow = read.split(","||"/");
                    rs2.add(OneRow);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
        //            
                }
            //BufferedReader to Read through CSV Contents
                  reader.close();

    }//end try 
        catch(Exception ex){
        String errmsg = ex.getMessage();
        //System.out.println("File not Found: "+errmsg);
    }//end exception handling
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this;

```
while (reader.readLine() != null) {
    String read = reader.readLine();// bufferedreader string variable
    String[] rawRow = read.split(",");
    String lastEntry = rawRow[rawRow.length - 1]; // this contains Member No/branchno
    String[] properLastEntry = lastEntry.split("/"); // this contains Member No, branchno
    String[] oneRow = new String[rawRow.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(rawRow, 0, oneRow, 0, rawRow.length - 1);
    System.arraycopy(properLastEntry, 0, oneRow, oneRow.length - 2, 2);
}
```

If you don't want to hard code the length of `2` in the `properLastEntry` array, you can do something like this instead

```
while (reader.readLine() != null) {
    String read = reader.readLine();// bufferedreader string variable
    String[] rawRow = read.split(",");
    String lastEntry = rawRow[rawRow.length - 1]; // this contains Member No/branchno
    String[] properLastEntry = lastEntry.split("/"); // this contains Member No, branchno as entries

    // create a memory which can contain rawRow and properLastEntry in a single
    // array
    String[] oneRow = new String[rawRow.length - 1 + properLastEntry.length];
    // copy the data for the finalRow
    System.arraycopy(rawRow, 0, oneRow, 0, rawRow.length - 1);
    System.arraycopy(properLastEntry, 0, oneRow, oneRow.length - properLastEntry.length,
            properLastEntry.length);
}
```

Comment: do I do that within the while loop?

Comment: is it possible to take each row and add it to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You want to split string based on two delimiters so you can mention multiple delimiters as follows

```
split(",|/")
```

Please go through the below link.
[Use string split() with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters)