# Javascript how to split string by multiple delimiters and include them in the result

Tags: javascript, regex, delimiter

I'm trying to separate string by multiple delimiters and include them in the result. Considering all consecutive non-whitespace characters as individual words. Example: "I'm working on a new super-project wow. Yay!" becomes "!Yay .wow project-super new a on working I'm"
My code sofar:

```
function test(string){
    console.log(string.split(/([.'\!'+a-zA-Z]+)/g ).reverse().join(' ') );
}

var string ="I'm working on a new super-project wow. Yay!"
test(string)
```

the output so far is: 
 Yay!   wow.   project - super   new   a   on   working   I'm

I'm still getting the wrong result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Current accepted answer keeps `super-project` as is but it should be `project-super`. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50107371/1020526).

Comment: Roman, your *Considering all consecutive non-whitespace characters as individual words* requirement clashes with the expected result. My answer is in line with that requirement. Please make sure you selected the right answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest swapping words with the glued punctuation first (using `.replace(/(^|\s)(\w+)([^\w\s]+)(?!\S)/g,"$1$3$2")`) and then match all non-whitespace chunks and join with a space:

```js
function test(string){
    console.log(string.replace(/(^|\s)(\w+)([^\w\s]+)(?!\S)/g,"$1$3$2").match(/\S+/g).reverse().join(' ') );
}
//"!Yay .wow project-super new a on working I'm"
var string ="I'm working on a new super-project wow. Yay!"
test(string)
```

The word-punctuation swapping regex details:

- `(^|\s)` - Group 1: start of string or whitespace
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `([^\w\s]+)` - Group 3: any 1+ words other than word and whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace char is allowed immediately to the right of the current location. Together with `(^|\s)`, these subpatterns form *whitespace word boundaries*.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are not so clear, there may be more cases to include but if not, splitting on `[!?.\s-]+` (or whatever delimiters are) would be a solution. You don't need to hack into `.replace()` or `.match()` methods:

```js
var str = "I'm working on a new super-project wow. Yay!";
console.log(str.split(/([!?.\s-])/g).reverse().join(''));
```