# Python split based off a string between two characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

How to split based off two characters `"["` & `"]"` in a string. For example calling .split() on the following would give...

```
x = "[Chorus: Rihanna & Swizz Beatz]
I just wanted you to know
...more lyrics
[Verse 2: Kanye West & Swizz Beatz]
I be Puerto Rican day parade floatin'
... more lyrics"

x.split()
print(x)
```

would give

```
["I just wanted you to know ... more lyrics", " be Puerto Rican day parade floatin' ... more lyrics]
```

This is different from the duplicate because its not splitting by multiple delimiters, its splitting by text enclosed in brackets when the text isnt necessarily known...

Comment: try x.split(\[|\\\]).       Checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993779/use-string-split-with-multiple-delimiters), may also help you.

Comment: @xXxpRoGrAmmErxXx This is not splitting by multiple delimiters. This is splitting by text enclosed in brackets.

Comment: @SvenMarnach How exactly does that dupe apply to this question? See ^ this comment.

Comment: I dont think this applies as a dupe?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to you, it might be helpful to someone in the future. The answerers would have also put an effort in writing their answer, which would no longer be useful if you have removed the content from the post. Also, note that by posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split("[\[\]]", x)`

**Using Regex:**

```
import re
x = """[Chorus: Rihanna & Swizz Beatz]
I just wanted you to know
...more lyrics
[Verse 2: Kanye West & Swizz Beatz]
I be Puerto Rican day parade floatin'
... more lyrics"""

print(filter(None,re.split("[\[\]]", x)[::2]))
```

**Output:**

```
['\nI just wanted you to know\n...more lyrics\n', "\nI be Puerto Rican day parade floatin'\n... more lyrics"]
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to split the song into verses, rather than just removing the contents in square brackets.

Comment: @SvenMarnach. Thanks. I did not understand OPs que

Comment: This'll give you an empty string as the first element in the output. You should probably remove that.

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Thanks

Comment: This helps a bit, how would you go about storing the removed string in another variable?

Comment: `newVariable = filter(None,re.split("[\[\]]", x)[::2])` ?