# Split a String by multiple delimiters in java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

what is the possible way to split a String by multiple delimiters? Is StringTokenizer can help me out to achieve this?

```
String str="list1|10456103|10456102|10456121#list2|10456105|10456122";
String str="list1|10513846#list2|";
String str3="list1#list2|10509855";
String str4="list2|10481812|";
String str5="list1|10396496|";
String str6="list1#list2|";
```

So now I should be able to extract only the long values :

```
For Str1  Finallist=[10456103,10456102,10456121,10456105,10456122]
For Str2  Finallist=[10513846]     
For Str3  Finallist=[10509855]
For Str4  Finallist=[10481812]
For Str5  Finallist=[10396496]
For Str6  Finallist[]
```

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: You can find a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993823/4370843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split them using the `split` method for String in java, then check if it's numeric or not.

the string is split by having `#` or `|` or `,` once or more than once.

then the split strings are tested to be numeric or not, as so:

```
    public static void main(String []args){
    String str="list1|10456103|10456102|10456121#list2|10456105|10456122";
    
    String arr[] = str.split("[|,#]+");
    
    for(String s: arr){
        try{
            int num=Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.println(num + " is a number"); //add to list
        }catch(Exception err) {
            System.out.println(s + " is not a number"); //don't add to list
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to have the words list1 and list2 in the final list.The final list just needs to contain only the data that is numbers like 10456103, 10456102 etc

Comment: i know.. that's why check for the numbers and only take them.. i printed out the lists to show that they're not numbers only

Answer (score 1):

For your consideration you can also convert them to a map of lists on the fly for later processing.

It works as follows:

- Split each String on `[|#]`
- filter on numbers only matching on `\\d+`
- convert to a long
- and save to a list

The `LinkedHashMap` simply preserves processing order in the final map.  It is not really required for this to work.

```
String[] strings = { str1, str2,str3,str4,str5,str6 };
Map<String, List<Long>> map = IntStream
        .range(0, strings.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i->"str"+(i+1),
                i->Arrays.stream(strings[i].split("[|#]"))
                        .filter(str->str.matches("\\d+"))
                        .map(Long::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                        (a,b)->a, LinkedHashMap::new));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
str1=[10456103, 10456102, 10456121, 10456105, 10456122]
str2=[10513846]
str3=[10509855]
str4=[10481812]
str5=[10396496]
str6=[]
```